# Hazelcast Scheduled Executor always starts task on newest member

Tags: hazelcast, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using Hazelcast Scheduled Executor Service in order to run a specific task, on one service instance only. In order to achieve this behavior we take advantage of com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.TaskUtils.named(java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) decorator to avoid duplicate tasks.

Hazelcast dependencies used:

```
implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.2" 
implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-kubernetes:2.2.2" // DNS Lookup
```

We use a hazelcast cluster with one member per service instance

Code example:

```
public void scheduleTask() {
    IScheduledExecutorService es = hazelcastInstance.getScheduledExecutorService("myScheduledExecutor");
    try {
        es.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("taskName", task)), 0, 30, SECONDS);
    } catch (DuplicateTaskException ex) {
        System.out.println("Task was already scheduled!");
    }
}
```

The above example manages to partially achieve the desired behavior. The only issue is that every time a new instance spins up, the scheduled executor will run the task on that specific instance. This is not ideal since we would like the task to execute, for example, once every 6 hours.

Is there any way to configure the scheduled executor so that it maintains running the task on the original instance it started and transfers to another instance only if the original one goes down?

Comment: Are you sure the task always moves to the newest member ? For me it is random. Often the newest but not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I used was to dispose already scheduled task and schedule again with an initial delay which I calculate based on the last time the task was scheduled.

Something like:

```
public void scheduleTask() {
    IScheduledExecutorService es = hazelcastInstance.getScheduledExecutorService("myScheduledExecutor");
    try {
        disposePreviousScheduledTasks(es);
        es.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("taskName", task)), initialDelay, 30, SECONDS);
    } catch (DuplicateTaskException ex) {
        System.out.println("Task was already scheduled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to dispose the task by name? I don't see such api /

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible, but there is an approximation.

`IScheduledExecutorService` does not provide a method to provide an ordering for which members to use.

- You can submit a task to a specific member, but this won't failover to a member of your choosing if the original specific member dies.
- ... various other options ...
- Or the option in your code, `scheduleAtFixedRate` which will pick a member, and this may be a different member each time the cluster changes size. It should not always be the newest unless by co-incidence.

What you could do is have a scheduled task that selects a member to run an ordinary task upon. One task that launches another.

In the scheduled task, the `run()` could call `hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getMembers()` to get the list of members in the cluster. All it needs is some logic to pick a member, and then do `hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("default").executeOnMember(runnable, member)`.

You might pick a member with a specific attribute that you configure. Or a member with a specific IP. Perhaps simplest is to pick the oldest, since this doesn't change until the oldest leaves, in which case 2nd olest is now oldest, easy failover.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Neil. I guess my main issue is the fact that the scheduler triggers automatically when the hazelcast cluster gets rebalanced even though the period hasn't passed. Do you know of a way to avoid this? I would like to execute the task only if the required period has passed, as long as I still have minimum one service instance running, not every time a new member joins or when some member goes down.

Comment: Again, more hacking might get you there. You could use [StatefulTask](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0-BETA-2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/scheduledexecutor/StatefulTask.html) or have the runnable/callable use an [IAtomicLong](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0-BETA-2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/cp/IAtomicLong.html) to note when it last ran.